# I can Find a record with MongoDB official Golang drivers, but the record is empty

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to learn Go and I wrote a little code that handles a MongoDB test database, inserting some general "items".
This is the code:

```
https://pastebin.com/ptNwKbk2
```

I can insert and update records without issues but when I try to FindOne or Find a record what comes out is some empty shell, it finds the record but the record only shows its id.
First Find [line 89]:

```
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&resultItem)
```

Result:

```
Found a single document: {ID:ObjectID("5cb488c30eeb652e64ecdaeb") itemID: priority:0 desc:}
```

Second Find [line 95]:

```
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), emptyFilter, findOptions)
```

Result, every element has an id but no data inside ("itemID: priority:0 desc:"):

```
Found multiple documents (array of pointers): [0xc00004c840 0xc00004c8c0]
```

Could someone find what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you unmarshal into? If it is a struct, you must export its fields!

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with, including the definition of your data type struct, preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The members of Items must start with an uppercase letter (just the variable names, the json/bson tags are fine) otherwise the deserializer can't access them.